# C#.net draw on tabcontrol and specific tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, draw, tabcontrol

recently i tried draw a rectangle on win from and this is the code

```
namespace GDI1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //i want do the below lines for specific tab page :)

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender , System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(50, 50, 530, 40));

        }
    }
}
```

now i want do the same thing but on specific tag page .... how can i set the codes for tabcontrol.

[image: what i tried]
[image: what i want]

Comment: Use the paint event for TabPage2.

Comment: private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler( tabPage2_Paint);
        }  ...here i get problem ..... like this?

Comment: Not in the click event.  In your code above, change `this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);` to `tabPage2.Paint += tabPage2_Paint;`  Copy your Form1_Paint method and change it to tabPage2_Paint.

Comment: ... and move those lines of code from the load event to the constructor.  Load event is only used when the dimension of the form is important to know.

Comment: thank you.... good tip for me  <3